# Logstash stdout - write into file

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

Am using logstash to get data from Oracle DB to Elastic Search. I used `stdout { codec => rubydebug }` its printing log in console. I want to write into a file.

How can we write the log into a file.

Please find my logstash config file.

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "D:\1SearchEngine\data\ojdbc8.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"
    jdbc_user => "demo"
    jdbc_password => "1234567"
    statement => "select * from product"    


 }
}

output {

     stdout { codec => rubydebug }  

  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "replacement"
    document_id => "%{ID}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
logstash.bat -f [path to config file] >> [path to log file]
```

For example:

```
 logstash.bat -f myconfig.config >> "C:\Users\test\Desktop\log.txt"
```

Note: Make sure the file has write permissions given to the process.

Comment: Am executing this command in windows not in unix., will it work ?

Comment: Sorry I don’t know if it’s different in Unix.. but why don’t you give it a try and work your way there. Let me know if I can help